# Parse JSON string to get a few reference data

Tags: c#, json

How can I parse the given string in C#? 
I want to extract the following values - username & ref_id

```
{
   "User":{
      "username":"Vinayaka",
      "email":"Vinayaka@mindsol.in",
      "ref_id":"43523543",
      "state_code":"UP",
      "active_status":"1",
      "user_type":"Admin",
      "last_active":"2018-09-22 13:50:23"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's four different ways of parsing your JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON which is one of the most common C# libraries to use for parsing JSON.

**Example 1**

Deserialization to our own class structure:

Usage:

```
Root output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
var refId = output.SomeUser.ReferenceId;
```

Class structure:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class representing the JSON
/// </summary>
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("User")]
    public User SomeUser { get; set; }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string EMail { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ref_id")]
        public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

Using dynamic types:

```
dynamic rootObject = JObject.Parse(json);
dynamic user = rootObject.User;
var refId = user.ref_id;
var username = user.username;
```

**Example 3**

Token/string property names and generic to extract value:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
var refId = root["User"]["ref_id"].Value<string>();
var username = root["User"]["username"].Value<string>();
```

**Example 4**

Using select tokens:

```
var rootObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var refId = rootObject.SelectToken("User.ref_id");
var username = rootObject.SelectToken("User.username");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.7.2) to parse string to JSON [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) Object

Here is an example,

```
var jsonStr = @"{
                    ""User"":{
                              ""username"":""Vinayaka"",
                              ""email"":""Vinayaka@mindsol.in"",
                              ""ref_id"":""43523543"",
                              ""state_code"":""UP"",
                              ""active_status"":""1"",
                              ""user_type"":""Admin"",
                              ""last_active"":""2018-09-22 13:50:23""
                             }
                        }";

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = json.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonStr);

foreach(KeyValuePair<string,object> p in data["User"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", p.Key, p.Value));
}
```

You can also check for [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may have a look at this "Quick and Dirty" approach.

Two simple methods:

```
static string QuickAndDirtyJsonLookupText(string json, string key) =>
    QuickAndDirtyJsonFind(json, key).Split('"')[1];
static string QuickAndDirtyJsonFind(string json, string key) {
    int keyIndex = json.IndexOf($"\"{key}\":");
    if (keyIndex < 0)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Key \"{key}\" not found in '{json}'.");
    return json.Substring(keyIndex + 3 + key.Length).TrimStart();
}
```

Lets you lookup what you need, for example:

```
const string json =
    "{"+
    "  \"User\":{" +
    "     \"username\":\"Vinayaka\"," +
    "     \"email\":\"Vinayaka@mindsol.in\"," +
    "     \"ref_id\":\"43523543\"," +
    "     \"state_code\":\"UP\"," +
    "     \"active_status\":\"1\"," +
    "     \"user_type\":\"Admin\"," +
    "     \"last_active\":\"2018-09-22 13:50:23\"" +
    "  }" +
    "}";
Assert.AreEqual("Vinayaka", QuickAndDirtyJsonLookupText(json, "username"));
Assert.AreEqual("43523543", QuickAndDirtyJsonLookupText(json, "ref_id"));
```

Of course, this is indeed "quick and dirty" and only works, if you know the structure of your json ahead of time, and if you know that the text values do not contain quotes - which is often the case. You can also easily add your own `QuickAndDirtyJsonLookupInt`, for instance.

If you want a more structured approach with full source code, check out my lightweight parser and generator on https://github.com/Dbquity/Json.